# Writing to a non-blocking NIO UDP (DatagramChannel) socket after processing request on a separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, nio, nonblocking

I'm experimenting with some network code, and I'm trying to figure out a good way to trigger writes to my DatagramChannel after having processed an event on a separate thread. This is quite simple for TCP, since you have a separate socket on which you can register your write interest (see reactor pattern, etc). For UDP, however, registering and deregistering interest with the datagram channel doesn't work so well, since I'm basically just modifying the same selection key.

I feel like you either block on the send in the event handler thread (wrong because then we're using blocking sends), or you block on a queue or something to take the responses and write them (also wrong because then we're blocking the selector thread).

I'd like to do something like switch the interest to write once I have something to write, and then back again to read, but then I run the risk of a race where I set it back to read after a write has been queued up, and then that write waits until I get the next read, which is also bad.

Yes, I know that there are other, potentially better suited threading models for these sorts of things, but I'm experimenting, so I'm curious. =)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set the interest-ops to write when you want to write. Just write, from whatever thread you happen to be in. Only if that write returns zero do you need to worry about write interest-ops, as per many answers here.

Comment: That seems like a bit of a flaky assumption, though. Eventually the write buffers will start to get full, and the write will return 0 more and more often. Eventually you'll get to a point where you've saturated it, and you'll need to change the interestedOps anyway. I imagine you get there pretty quickly under very heavy load.

Comment: @MarkusJevring There is no 'assumption' here. There is nothing in the documentation that states that you have to wait for `OP_WRITE` before you can write. The rest of you comment *agrees* with what I have stated here.